# Removing column and header information when writing a string to .txt

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create code to write all my inputs for another program that reads .txt files. 
I cannot just export my string to a txt file outright because it is surrounded by other text

**I import the data with:**
`inputs = str(pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=None, index_col=0))`

**and then write it with:

**+inputs +** in this chunk of text

```
'LINES_R: 23\n'
'' + inputs +''
'\n'
'GENERATORS: 113\n'
'AM0    IGH 1   64  0   5.55    0   6   1\n'
```

**However when it comes out it always has headers, or when I make the first line of data a header, there will be an indent like so**

```
      1  2       3         4         5  6
 0                                         
MDN  HEN  6   883.5  0.000046  0.300000  0
WKM  TKU  6   924.0  0.000055  0.023490  0
```

**what I need is just**

```
MDN  HEN  6   883.5  0.000046  0.300000  0
WKM  TKU  6   924.0  0.000055  0.023490  0
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

1. You can postprocess the string, along the lines of

```
'\n'.join(inputs.split('\n')[2:])
```

2. A cleaner method is to use the `DataFrame.to_string()` method, e.g.

```
inputs = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=None, index_col=0).to_string(header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, using pandas.to_string on import, thanks to Chris. 
to_string should be set to

`(header=None, index = None)`

which removes all numbers and header info making it good to print

`inputs = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=None, index_col=None).to_string(header=None, index = None)`